# How to call an Action Controller from a View and return it's output to the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller which takes two arguments. I would like to call this controller within my View and output the returning View() data in a .

It is possible with Ajax, but is it possible directly with MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` - http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: Can you define parameters with these methods?

Comment: Yes, see the 'Passing Values With RenderAction' section of the link I provided. You can pass parameters using an anonymous type syntax, where the type property names are matched with the action parameter names by convention.